# German flash cards with pictures and no English?

Tags: resource, vocabulary, mnemonic

I am looking to increase my German vocabulary and am looking for a good series of flash cards that does not contain any English, but instead just has pictures and the German word. Does such a thing exist? I have tried Googling, the Apple Store and Droid Store, but have always found flash cards with English words.

Comment: You might want to check with a German catalogue company like Bertelsmann and order German children's items, etc. Materials intended for anything other than German only will have the other language on them. That's kind of the point.

Comment: I also immediately thought of children's books with this description. But unfortunately the vocabulary will likely be too small to be of use for an adult trying to learn German - unless they want to talk to a small child ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No flashcard, but perhaps a [`Bildwörterbuch`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bildw%C3%B6rterbuch) ([Visual dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_dictionary)) is a help:

- [Pons has a *Bildwörterbuch*](http://bildwoerterbuch.pons.eu/)
- [Hueber](http://www.hueber.de/seite/pg_bildwoerterbuch_dwb) has one with 1000 words.

I tried also a search for [Quartett](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartett_%28Kartenspiel%29)
There are some nice [cards for kids](http://www.hueber.de/sixcms/media.php/36/planet1L8-quartett.pdf), but I think you are looking for other cards.

There are some `[Kartenspiele für den Deutschunterricht][7]`, there is for example a page [`Quartett Berufe`](http://www.westfr.de/daf/quartett-berufe.htm)

[Wegerer.at](http://vs-material.wegerer.at/deutsch/d_daz1.htm) has also some nice pdfs.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because this book is wonderful. It does have English, but is almost exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

On this [**Goethe Institut page**](http://www.goethe.de/ins/pl/lp/prj/dwt/spi/deindex.htm), there's a cute Flash game (**Spiel 03: Memo-Spiel**) that does what you're looking for. Found it by searching on ""memo-spiel" bild wort lernen wortschatz", if you keep looking you may find more. Tried the search with "Memory-Spiel" instead of "Memo-Spiel" but got only links to articles not games. Possibly "Memory-Spiel" is trademarked and reserved to the original publisher.

You could make your own: glue a picture to a cardboard square, glue a word to another square. Repeat with additional word-picture pairs. Turn all squares face-down and start having fun!

Comment: On the making your own end - I actually am a software engineer. Do you think a product like that would be useful?

Comment: You mean, create a finished product using traditional flash cards, memory games, multimedia, on-screen interaction, user-controllable printouts, everything in color, bling-bling, eye candy? And then market it yourself or sell it to a publisher? It sounds like a terrific idea! However -- and please don't get upset, I don't want to sound discouraging -- but Langenscheidt already has done [all that and more](http://www.vokabeln.de/v6/bestellung.htm)... although right now only for English, French, Spanish, Italian, and Latin... but they could easily add German, too, at the drop of a hat.

Comment: In the meantime, here's [another memory game](http://www.goethe.de/lhr/prj/woe/mem/deindex.htm) from Goethe Institut: You match "emigrant" German words and phrases that have settled in other languages with their long-form explanations. Completely silly and great fun.